# How to convert a html table stored in a variable into a datatable and initialise export to excel

Tags: php, html, jquery, datatable

I have a php variable in which I'm storing a html table. Its a big table with a lot of data and headers and it'll be difficult for me to use PHPoffice to export the table so I wanted to convert the table to datatable and get the export option using datatable file export. I display the table using echo so when is use

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#tableId').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

the table does not get converted to datatable because im guessing the script loads first and then the table.

What would be the best method to get this stored table converted to excel with minimum coding.

Comment: `im guessing the script loads first and then the table.`...no because of the `$(function () {` (unless of course the table is loaded via ajax)

Comment: How is this table created? Can you post a sample?